# Myrrix REST API - does function Set / Add Preference automatically omit the preferred item in recommendations?

Tags: recommendation-engine, myrrix

My setup is 500K rows of 200K users and 2K items with no preference values (i.e. the default preference value is 1.0).

Normally, the recommendation engine does not recommend the items user already has preference for. This is ok, since I dont want to get recommendations for already listed user-item relations. But I want to later provide the engine with additional preferences to items, either positive or negative, but these items should be on the possible recommended list.

Regarding Myrrix API call `Set / Add Preference` (http://myrrix.com/rest-api/#setaddpreference): will any such added preference for an item automatically disable it from the list of possible recommendations for the particular user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `considerKnownItems` to `true` in [`recommend()`](http://myrrix.com/docs/serving/javadoc/net/myrrix/common/MyrrixRecommender.html#recommend%28long,%20int,%20boolean,%20org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.recommender.IDRescorer%29), then it will not exclude any items at all from the results. (Similarly, the raw REST API has a parameter "...`&considerKnownItems=true...`)

Then, you can perform your own custom filtering one of two ways, by either implementing `CandidateFilter` or `RescorerProvider`. See http://myrrix.com/tuning-quality/. `CandidateFilter` may be faster and more appropriate for this case, but `RescorerProvider` gives you a hook to do more customization later if desired.

Yes, setting any value for a user-item pair excludes it from recommendations by default.